# Mosfet drive heating issue

Tags: motor-controller, mosfet-driver

I am trying to drive a motor/lamp (10 Amp Max). The voltage across the load will be controlled via an N-Mosfet. I started building the mosfet drive part and I'm kinda stuck.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUNV0m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The FET heats up when barely 1-2 Amps are flowing through. I never faced a problem when used these same FETs on an H bridge configuration driven by DRV8701P with the same amount of heat sinks. Also tried making Totem Pole driver using BJTs, same issue. Changed FETs several times.

Also, some of my FETs went bad, dont know why. Their drain and source terminals shorted out. On some, all of the three terminals shorted out. I have changed around 8-10 FETs on this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One concern I see is that that 470uF cap is probably electrolytic.  Is it polarized?  Connected the right way?  Are you using an inductor like a motor or a lamp?  Is there a chance a polarized capacitor was reverse voltaged and is now shorting?  Is the diode connected backwards?  Have you measured the voltage coming out of your mosfet driver?

Comment: Polarities are correct, I'll check the voltages at gate and post as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: I checked the output of the gate driver ZXGD3005E6, and its merely 5 Volts. Checked the datasheet, looks like it has to be given a 12V pwm to get 11.2V drive. I'll do it and post the update.

Answer (score 2):

The big mistake it seems is that you have a 470 uF capacitor across the load and this is going to be a killer when it comes to PWM control of the motor: -

[image]

Every time your PWM activates the MOSFET you take a massive pulse of current because of that capacitor. Get rid of it.

Comment: Okay, I'll remove the Cap and try again. AFAIK, I inserted the cap after few FETs failed. Anyways, I'll remove it for now.

Comment: Also, where did you buy the MOSFETs from. There are a few fakes around supplied by less reputable dealers.

Comment: Well I bought directly from Mouser. And these from the same reel are working perfectly with an H bridge driver which i made few weeks back.